# audio recording by python

Tags: python, audio

I am using python to process the audio signal. I would like to record a signal and keep its SPL level. I am using pyaudio Library to do that. Here is the example I found. However, I find the signal is around 18db larger then it should be. Is there a way to change the recorded signal amplitude in the file wav? Second question is for the wav file, data are coded in signed 16 bits. I have the impression that the negative values are coded using Two's complement can anyone confirm this please?

Thank you very much!

```
enter code here def record(output_file_name, rec_device_id=None):
# Sampling = Data is recorded per batches of 1024 bits
CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
# Sampling = 48kHz
RATE = 48000
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = output_file_name

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                    input_device_index=rec_device_id)
# Sampling = 48kHz
print("*** recording start ***")

frames = []

rms=np.zeros(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS+1)
for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    #print("*** data ***",data)
    #decoded = struct.unpack('h',data)
    print("*** decoded ***",decoded)
    frames.append(data)
    rms[i] = audioop.rms(data, 2)

print("*** recording done ***")
print("*** rms ***",rms)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(output_file_name,  'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```